# Do I draw a card in this situation with Oblivion Ring in MTG?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Situation:

My opponent has an [Oblivion Ring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOblivion%20Ring%5d) exiling my [Wirewood Savage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWirewood%20Savage%5d). I play [Beast Within](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBeast%20Within%5d) targeting the Oblivion Ring.

The following things will happen:

- The oblivion ring will be destroyed
- A beast will be put on the battlefield
- My Wirewood Savage will come back

But in what order? I want to know whether or not I'll be able to draw a card by Wirewood Savage's effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You will not draw a card.

When a spell or ability resolves it resolves fully, then all abilities that were triggered during that resolution are put on the stack immediately after.

Beast Within resolves fully, destroying Oblivion Ring and creating a beast.
Oblivion Ring's 'leaves the battlefield' ability it put on the stack.
The ability resolves, bringing back Wirewood Savage.

### Modern versions of Oblivion Ring such as [Ixalan's Binding](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIxalan%27s%5d%2b%5bBinding%5d) use a different template.  For those, you *would* draw a card.

Ixalan's Binding reads

> When Ixalan's Binding enters the battlefield, exile target nonland permanent an opponent controls until Ixalan's Binding leaves the battlefield.

This creates a one-shot effect (exiling a permanent) that lasts "until" Ixalan's Binding leaves the battlefield.  As per rule 610.3:

> 610.3. Some one-shot effects cause an object to change zones “until” a specified event occurs. A second one-shot effect is created immediately after the specified event. This second one-shot effect returns the object to its previous zone.

Wirewood Savage would return to the battlefield immediately after Ixalan's Binding leaves play.  Then you would create a Beast token, and because Wirewood Savage is in play, Wirewood Savage would trigger.

Comment: So one-shot effects can happen halfway through the resolution of a spell or ability? They don't have to wait until a player next has priority?